# Proof of cardinalities sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove that the cardinality of set $A^{B+C}$ is equal to the cardinality of $A^{B}\times A^{C}$.

I think I need to make functions from $B+C$ to $A$ and one from $B$ to $A$ and one from $A$ to $C$. I don't know what to do after that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a function from the (disjoint) union of $B$ and $C$ to $A$, and you need to transform this to a pair of functions, one from $B$ to $A$ and the other from $C$ to $A$. A natural thing to try, is $$f \mapsto (f\upharpoonright B, f \upharpoonright C)$$
Now we need to show that this is one-to-one and onto. Suppose $(f\upharpoonright B, f \upharpoonright C) = (g\upharpoonright B, g \upharpoonright C)$, then 
$g$ agrees with $f$ when we restrict to $B$ and $C$ separately. Hence $g$ and $f$ agree on the disjoint union of $B$ and $C$, but as this is the whole domain of $g$ and $f$, then $f = g$.

Now suppose we have a pair of function $(g,h)\in B^A\times C^A$, we want to build a function mapping to this. Try
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) & \text{if }x\in B \\ h(x) &\text{if }x\in C\end{cases} $$
Then $f$ is well-defined on $B+C$ and $f \mapsto(g,h)$, so our correspondence is onto.